# SpringFrameWork Injected bean is null?

Tags: multithreading, spring, spring-mvc, null, javabeans

I am working on SpringFrameWork and MySQL.

I did some test and communication between DB and framework works fine.
The problem is when I use Injected bean in Class which extends Thread, Somehow bean becomes null. I do not know why.

Below is part of my Spring controller which create Thread extended Object('IISDaemon').

```
@RequestMapping("/list")
public ModelAndView list(
        @RequestParam(value="page_no", defaultValue="1") Integer page_no) 
        throws Exception{
    log.info("Manager called Web page. page no : " + page_no);
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

    //test
        log.info("svc bean : " + svc);
        IISDaemon daemon = new IISDaemon();
        daemon.start();

    //


    mav.setViewName("/iis/list");
    mav.addObject("list", svc.list(page_no));
    return mav;
}
```

And below is Class IISDaemon.

```
public class IISDaemon extends Thread {
    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    @Inject 
    IISSVCImpl svc;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        log.info("Daemon starts.");
        ArrayList<IISVO> list = new ArrayList<IISVO>();
        try{
            log.info("svc bean : " + svc);
            list = (ArrayList<IISVO>)svc.jobList(1);
            for(IISVO vo : list){
                this.sleep(5000);
                log.info(vo);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }   
};
```

As you can see, I print 2 logs in each class.
The upper one is

"`INFO : org.owls.iis.IISMgrController - svc bean : org.owls.iis.svc.IISSVCImpl@4572`".

And Lower one is

"`INFO : org.owls.iis.daemon.IISDaemon - svc bean : null`"

Thanks for your advice in advance :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not injected because `IISDaemon` is not a Spring managed class.  You are instantiating it in your controller class with the `new` operator.

Perhaps you would rather inject the `IISDaemon` into your controller class, and then provide the injected value to your `ISSDaemon` via its constructor.

Comment: Thanks for advice. But the form that I want in final version is little different. 'IISDaemon' should start immediately as WAS starts. And it need to access Database(that is why I inject service class in daemon.).

Comment: So I added IISDaemon as a bean in root-context.(like your first sentence.) And because of purpose(as I added comment), I put init-method = "start". So my solution looks like <bean name="daemon" class="org.owls.iis.IISDaemon" init-method="start"/>. And it still does not work. Thanks but can you suggest other ideas? :D Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I have rebuild the program.
And it works fine now.
I can not remember exactly what situation I was in, but probably nicholas's answer is right.
Maybe I could missing resist bean to root-context.xml or @Component.
Thanks for reading this question.